# Cannot register application into office 365

Tags: c#, sharepoint, windows-store-apps, office365

I have installed the Office 365 API Tools in order to connect my app to my Sharepoint stored in Office 365. Nonetheless when I add a connected service to my solution, it asks for my credentials, until here I do not have any problem. Then, I connect and Visual Studio (2013) attempt to register my application and an error occured: "name".

I do not have any further information on the dialog displaying the error... Does anyone already had this error and have a solution which fix it?

Thanks for you help :) 
.x

Comment: Are you able to manually register an app from the AAD management portal?

Comment: @DorreneBrown Oops, nope... I assume it's mandatory in order to use O365 within windows store apps ?

Comment: Registering an app within AAD is required to use the Office 365 APIs. VS usually does that step for you when you add a connected service. If you're able to register an app within the AAD management portal it rules out AAD being wonky, which means a reinstall of the O365 tools will probably solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above - are you able to manually register an app using the AAD management portal (located at http://manage.windowsazure.com)? If so, it rules out any issues with Azure and means your tooling is messed up or out of date.

If you're not updated to the most recent version of the O365 tooling (last update was October 2014), make sure to update and try again. If you are updated on the tooling and are able to manually register your app, reinstalling the O365 tools for VS will likely solve your issue.